# undefined evaluating frames.endCoordinates.height

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

i had upgraded RN to 0.59.1 and updated native base to 2.13.5.
getting error

> "undefined frames.endCoordinates.height"

when i try for `textinput`.
`Native-Base` Content is internally using 
`react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`

this is function from `KeyboardAwareHOC` of `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`

```js
 _updateKeyboardSpace = (frames: Object) => {
      if (this.props.enableAutomaticScroll) {
        let keyboardSpace: number =
          frames.endCoordinates.height + this.props.extraScrollHeight
        if (this.props.viewIsInsideTabBar) {
          keyboardSpace -= _KAM_DEFAULT_TAB_BAR_HEIGHT
        }
```

Comment: Wecome to Stackoverflow! Please consider editing your question to add some code to better explain your problem, because as it stands, it is very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I can't grasp your intentions with your question. But what you want to do seems like this.

```js
<KeyboardAwareScrollView
  onKeyboardWillShow={(frames: Object) => {
    console.log('Keyboard event', frames)
  }}>
```

Is this right? You just saw the code in which the '`react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`' module was made.